# Select by Date from a DataTable

Tags: c#

[image]

i have a dataTable that contain the data in the image can i select from it all the rows that contain the same date.for example all the row that has 'Mar 18 2013'

Comment: Try '20130318', that is the way you pass dates to SQL, might work here

Comment: yes u can just pass the date value and select the columns from the table

Comment: Is the above a representation of a `C#` `DataTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following if your `CHAT_DATE` is of type `DateTime`

```
var query = from t in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            where t.Field<DateTime>("CHAT_DATE").Date == new DateTime(2013,03,18)
            select t;
```

If your `CHAT_DATE` is of type string then you have to convert it first to DateTime, using DateTime.ParseExact and then query like:

```
var query = from t in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            where DateTime.ParseExact(t.Field<string>("CHAT_DATE"), "MMM d yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date ==
            new DateTime(2013,03,18)
            select t;
```

You may see: [Queries in LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tlbName where CHAT_DATE like 'Mar 18 2013'%
```

Try out this one.